# Problemas de estilos con paginate laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, paginación

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy haciendo una paginacion en laravel y tengo el problema que a la hora de mostrarla en mi pagina se ve de una forma rara, esta es la forma en la que hago mi paginacion desde el **home.blade.php**:

```
public function index()
{
    $data = Books::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(3);
    return view('home', [
        'data' => $data
    ]);
}
```

Y esta es la forma en la que incluyo la paginacion:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
   {{ $data->links() }}
</div>
```

Y de esta forma es en la que me lo muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me podría decir como puedo hacer que se vea "normal" o al menos como se veia en la version 5 de laravel. Desde ya gracias a todos :).

Comment: ¿Estás usando tailwind o alguna otra librería para los estios?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ solo uso bootstrap

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ vaya, gracias así ya se ve normal, perdón si el error es muy basico pero soy nuevo en laravel :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la versión 8, laravel trae como predeterminados los estilos de [Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) para la paginación, pero también incluye vistas de paginación creadas con [Bootstrap CSS](https://getbootstrap.com/).

Para usar estas vistas en lugar de las de Tailwind, puedes llamar al método `useBootstrap` del paginador dentro del método `boot` de tu clase `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`:

```php
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```

Referencia: Pagination [Usando Bootstrap](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#using-bootstrap)