# Flecha gigante en paginación de Laravel

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, laravel-livewire, livewire

Hola estoy implementado la paginación de laravel en livewire, pero graficamente deja una flecha gigante.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
he visto que una solución generalizada para esto es usar la siguiente linea en la vista: {{$clientes->links('pagination::bootstrap-4')}}

esto funciona gráficamente, pero no es funcional ya que al hacer clic en una pagina manda el siguiente error:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/livewire/message/clients?page=2

Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "405 Method Not Allowed".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como puedo solucionar esto?, el log no muestra ningún error.

Comment: La pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de este sitio, que es el español.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problemas de estilos con paginate laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/494308/problemas-de-estilos-con-paginate-laravel)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Buen día,

Vi que cambiaste el idioma de tu pregunta así estoy editando la respuesta y agrego la solución en español.

Cuando usas livewire, los componentes usan tailwind por defecto, para utilizar por ejemplo paginación con bootstrap debes poner

```
protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
```

En tu componente, de esa forma configuras el tema de la paginación a bootstrap

Si deseas utilizar bootstrap con livewire vas a tener que modificar o hacer tus componentes para que trabajen con bootstrap y no con tailwind

Que tengas buen día

/********* Respuesta original cuando la pregunta estaba en inglés *********/
First of all, you posted your question in StackOverflow in Spanish so your question might be downvoted for not using the correct site

Anyway I hope this answer helps you

When you are using livewire, by default it uses tailwind so the pagination and other components will have the tailwind classes

To be able to use it with bootstrap you have to type:

```
protected $paginationTheme = 'bootstrap';
```

In your component, that will tell livewire to use bootstrap for the pagination theme

If you want to use bootstrap with livewire you will have to tweak most of the components

Hope it helps!

Have a good day